# Loop through an array of checkboxes and insert values

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, foreach, checkbox

First time posting, hope all goes well :)

Been working on this for a while but basically I'm doing something like this:  http://drupal.org/project/fancycheckboxes

I need to set a value of yes/no for each checkbox that I'm looping through and right now it works but is changing the value of all when I change one.

My foreach loop:

```
  <?php $object = new stdClass(); $i = 0; ?>
<?php foreach( $filters as $key => $value ) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="show_filter">Show <?php echo $object->$key = $value['filter']; ?> Filter</label></td>        
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="show_filter" <?php //if ( $row['active_filter'] === 'yes' ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php //} ?> name="dp_show_filter" value="<?php echo $object->$key = $value['active_filter']; ?>"/><?php echo $object->$key = $value['active_filter']; ?></td>
        <td><a class="button-primary" href="?page=profolio_theme&del=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $i++;
}
```

and my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

        $i = 0;
        customCheckbox = $('.dp_wrap input[type="checkbox"]');
        showFilter = $('.dp_wrap input[name="dp_show_filter"]');
        values = [];

            return customCheckbox.each(function() {

                // the element
                var el = this;

                // Hide checkbox
                $(this).hide();

                // Replace element
                var rep = $('<a href="#"><span></span></a>').addClass('dp-checkbox').insertAfter(this);

                // default state
                if( $(showFilter).val() === 'yes'){
                        $(showFilter).prop('checked', true);
                        $(rep).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
                    } else {
                        $(showFilter).prop('checked', false);
                        $(rep).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
                    }
                if($(this).is(':checked') ) {
                    $(rep).addClass('on');
                } else {
                    $(rep).addClass('off');
                }

                // Click event
                $(rep).click(function(e) {

                    e.preventDefault();

                    if( $(el).is(':checked') ) {

                        values.push($(showFilter).val('no'), ++$i);

                        $(el).prop('checked', false);
                        $(rep).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
                    } else {

                        values.push($(showFilter).val('yes'), ++$i);

                        $(el).prop('checked', true);
                        $(rep).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
                    }
                });
            });
});
```

Currenty my values are posting to a database as yes/no.

Any help is greatly appreciated and I hope my first post is an acceptable one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is changing all of the values as it looks as though you are giving the same name to every `checkbox` created on your page.

You can change your PHP code to something more like this:

```
<?php $object = new stdClass(); $i = 0; ?>
<?php foreach( $filters as $key => $value ) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><label for="show_filter">Show <?php echo $object->$key = $value['filter']; ?> Filter</label></td>        
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="show_filter" <?php //if ( $row['active_filter'] === 'yes' ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php //} ?> name="dp_show_filter_<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $object->$key = $value['active_filter']; ?>"/><?php echo $object->$key = $value['active_filter']; ?></td>
    <td><a class="button-primary" href="?page=profolio_theme&del=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
$i++;
}
```

Then change your `default state` to this and remove the if statement from underneath it:

```
// default state
if( $(this).val() === 'yes'){
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
    $(rep).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
} else {
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
    $(rep).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
}
```

I am pretty sure that will fix your problem as you described it.  It is hard to tell without a more complete example of your code.

Comment: What would be the best way to change the names dyamically while still using $_POST['some-name'] and in jQuery target those inputs without being too specific since I use this in other places?

Comment: I would use the `$key` or `$row['id']` after the text of the name you already have for the checkboxes.  Remember that names and ids cannot start with numbers.  So something like this:
`name="dp_show_filter_<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"`

Then, in your selection code, you can replace the `$(showFilter)` with `$(this)` as you are already operating on each checkbox in the collection.

And for that matter, you can also get rid of the extraneous block after the showfilter selections that is redoing your work over again.  I will update the code in my answer post.

Comment: that's true, not sure why I didn't think of that.  Would I need to do something different than $('.dp_wrap input[name="dp_show_filter"]') in the javascript?  Maybe use a class instead?

Comment: You are already selecting all the checkboxes within your `.dp_wrap` element (which I assume is what you want to do).  Thus making the changes I suggested above should still perform what you desire.  But, yes, for future proofing this code (especially for use in other places) it would add extra security to ensuring you select the right set of elements if you were to add a unique class name to the entire set.  Then replace `customCheckbox = $('.dp_wrap input[type="checkbox"]');` with `customCheckbox = $('.dp_wrap .checkbox_class_name');`. You can get rid of the following `showFilter` line too.

Comment: I'll give it a go in the php but in the javascript, checking if val == yes might be too specific since I use this on other elements that don't use yes/no

Comment: This worked but I changed the javascript to detect ID instead of Name.  I did put $value['id'] in both name and ID.

My javascript is different in that I took out the global showFilter, instead used a parseInt(this.id.replace) and showFilter("#show_filter" + id)

However, it's not posting any actual values now to the database.  In my dump it shows the array updated when a value was changed to yes, it does nothing when changed to no.  Checking the DB, the values were not posted.

Ideas?

Comment: also I should note that I change the post to:

$active = isset($_POST['dp_show_filter_[$i]']);

Answer (score 0):

You iterate through your  `customCheckbox` array with an `each`, but inside your loop, you access `$(showFilter)`, which is a global array.

Did you mean `$(showFilter[i])` ?

The [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) callback receives `i` (the index in the loop) as a parameter :

```
return customCheckbox.each(function(i) {
    ...

    if( $(showFilter[i]).val() === 'yes'){ ...
```

Comment: I tried doing [] and [$i] while appending $i++ at the end and it broke the click functionality.

Comment: If you added the `[$i]` as suggested here then you are dual-purposing your `$i` variable as both an incrementer for the elements in your `.each()` function as well as an index for your `values[]` array.  If you instead added a `$j` to the mix for incrementing your `.each()` function it should work, but is not the best way of handling it.

Comment: I edited my answer. You should use the loop index, which is given as an argument to your `.each` callback.

Comment: this helped me get closer as I was able to get them to change individually but nothing is posting to the db now.

In addition to what you added, I added 
var id = parseInt(this.id.replace("show_filter_", ""));
var showFilter = $("show_filter_" + id);